# Need help with LM317 (500 mA) out of 3 volts supply Calculations

Tags: constant-current, lm317

Does LM317 regulate a constant current of 500 mA out of 3 volts supply (Vin) ? Need help with its associated calculations please. !

[image]

[image]

Comment: NO. The input MUST be 3 volts greater than the output, which cannot go below the ref voltage of 1.25 volts. Just for s safe margin I would not let Vin go below 5.0 vdc. What is the second schematic for?

Answer (score 4):

No.

LM317 has a dropout voltage of about 3 V. That means the output pin of LM317 must be at least 3 V below the input pin for proper regulation.

Furthermore, in this configuration the output node of the current source is 1.25 V below the output pin of the LM317 chip.

So the input must be at least 4.25 V to provide a regulated 500 mA output. And then it will only do so into a short circuit. The input voltage must be further increased by whatever you want the output compliance voltage to be if you're driving a load that produces any voltage drop with current running through it.

To put it in an equation, you need to have

$$V_{in} \ge V_{Output} + 4.25\ {\rm V}$$

for this circuit to maintain regulation.

Comment: Understood Thanks for help, actually I need to get out a regulated constant current of 500 mA for measuring a coil resistance (by ADC of a microcontroller) but the system will be running on a 3 volts, any suggestions for a suitable IC ?

Comment: @msayed, what's the maximum possible value of the coil resistance?

Comment: it seems that 317 is becoming the regulator equivalent of the 741 in questions here, 'can I use this old part at too low a voltage?'

Comment: @Neil_UK, I only  get aggravated if they call it an "LDO".

Comment: @ThePhoton there's also good reason to be upset when it's used as voltage or current reference for measuring things. It's not like it's exact in any of its values.

Comment: @The Photon, 6 ohms, the ADC 10 bits will calculate the range of coil's resistance starting of 0 : the minimum mV to detect No coil attached up to 1023 : 6 Ohms.

Comment: After doing some search, I found the LT1932 IC (circuit has been added in main question).. I'm going to read & study its datasheet to determine if it's able to provide constant current at 500 mA.. and maybe I get back to you here if I need help, further waiting your suggestions.

Comment: @msayed, if you're trying to light an LED, LT1932 should work great. There will be some ripple in the current output, so if you're using this current in an analog circuit somehow, it might not be so great.

Comment: @The Photon, so Could you please suggest for me a precision constant current source IC/or a circuit ?

Comment: If you have a new question, you can post it as a new question. Be sure to be clear about your accuracy requirement, current value, and whether you want a current source or sink.

Comment: But first do a google image search for "precision current source circuit".